# How can i make clickable map

Tags: javascript, json, svg

I want to make my map clickable by region but I don't understand how to do that. Am I supposted to edit the js file or the svg file?
Js file:
The path looks like this:

```
"g":{

"path":[
{
    "id":"GB",
    "title":"United Kingdom",           "d":"M459.38,281l-1.5,3.29l-2.12,-0.98l-1.73,0.07l0.58,-2.57l-0.58,-2.6l2.35,-0.2L459.38,281zM466.83,260.24l-3,5.73l2.86,-0.72l3.07,0.03l-0.73,4.22l-2.52,4.53l2.9,0.32l0.22,0.52l2.5,5.79l1.92,0.77l1.73,5.41l0.8,1.84l3.4,0.88l-0.34,2.93l-1.43,1.33l1.12,2.33l-2.52,2.33l-3.75,-0.04l-4.77,1.21l-1.31,-0.87l-1.85,2.06l-2.59,-0.5l-1.97,1.67l-1.49,-0.87l4.11,-4.64l2.51,-0.97l-0.02,0l-4.38,-0.75l-0.79,-1.8l2.93,-1.41l-1.54,-2.48l0.53,-3.06l4.17,0.42l0,0l0.41,-2.74l-1.88,-2.95l-0.04,-0.07l-3.4,-0.85l-0.67,-1.32l1.02,-2.2l-0.92,-1.37l-1.51,2.34l-0.16,-4.8l-1.42,-2.59l1.02,-5.36l2.18,-4.31l2.24,0.42L466.83,260.24z"
                },
        ]
    }
```

How can I use href here to link to Wikipedia, as example?
The map is working but it's not clickable. I wanna make a clickable world map. 
Can somebody help me ? 
Thank you!

Comment: Why is this tagged "dictionary"?

Comment: My bad, sorry. It's my first time.

Comment: That looks like json, how are you turning that into SVG?

Comment: Oh well, how can i link something in json?

Comment: Using JSON alone, you can't. You could use a script that loaded some JSON data and altered the SVG file's DOM accordingly, but you'd need to either write the script yourself or find one that did it.

Comment: i downloaded a map from google and it comes with svg files, js files and css files. The map is working but it isn't clickable. I just want to do that. For example, when i click on Usa or Uk, i want go to on wikipedia. And i don't know how to do that. What am i supposted to do now?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like AMCharts You can visit their site for more information on how to do what you're looking for.http://www.amcharts.com/demos/zooming-to-countries-map/

Comment: It is Am Charts. Can i link any country somehow? I can't find what i am looking for there.

Comment: What you will have to do is load the JS file from AMCharts on your webpage. What you have is a snippet of the code you will need more to load a map. Look at this JSFiddle and switch the country ISO code to GB like you want http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/V7Xq8/